# Running command line commands in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a command line command that accepts a few arguments in a specific format. The command syntax is as follows:

```
someCommand.exe arg1/arg2@arg3
```

The executable resides in a network drive, and command prompt doesn't support UNC paths, so I'm trying to use PowerShell instead to run it.

So far, running someCommand.exe from the network drive works. However, if I have some special characters in the arguments, the command breaks

For example, if the arguments have a semicolon, I'll get the following error:

> The term  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Also, when I encapsulate arguments with single or double quotes (for example when the arguments have spaces), it breaks the command as well.

Is there any way of sending the argument as-is to the command in PowerShell?

Comment: What's the command?  You can try to backquote the semicolon `;

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it up in quotes.

For example:

```
someCommand.exe "$($args[0])/$($args[1])@$($args[2])"
```